# Testing Alexa skill before submitting for certification

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to Alexa skill development. I ran through the [6 Steps to Build Your First Alexa Skill](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/content/fact-skill-1). I'm on the final step where it's asking me to Submit for Certification. Is there a way to test on an Alexa device prior to submitting for certification?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/testing-an-alexa-skill#h2_register

Answer (score 0):

To use an Alexa device or the Alexa Service Simulator with testing, following this (as mentioned above):
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/testing-an-alexa-skill#h2_register

You can test and debug your skill first locally on your device using Bespoken Tools:
https://bespoken.tools/blog/2016/08/24/introducing-bst-proxy-for-alexa-skill-development

Our proxy allows requests from Alexa to be sent straight to your device. In addition, you can use our [emulator](http://docs.bespoken.tools/en/latest/tutorials/tutorial_bst_emulator_nodejs/) to write unit tests for your skill.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in addition to testing on a simulator, there are two ways to test on an actual Alexa device:

1. If you have an Alexa device connected to your account, then you just need to ensure that the 'Enabled' switch on the test tab is enabled: 
   [image]
2. You can have your friends that have an Alexa device help you test by adding them as beta testers as described in this [Alexa blog post](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx2EN8P2AHAHO6Y/How-to-Add-Beta-Testers-to-Your-Skills-Before-You-Publish).